# How to forward email for an entire domain to an email address using SRS (Sender Rewriting Scheme)

Tags: email, forwarding, postfix, sendmail, mta

I have a domain for which I want to forward all email destined for addresses at that domain to a single email address. For example, I want to forward john@example.com and fred@exapmle.com and mary@example.com to the email address john.doe@gmail.com

I've currently set this up by pointing my domain's MX record to my server running Postifx  2.3.3 under CentOS 5.7. This succeeds in forwarding the emails however I've been unable to get [Sender Rewriting Scheme](http://www.openspf.net/SRS) working which results in many of the forwarded emails being categorized as spam.

So, I don't care what MTA I use (sendmail, postfix, exim, etc) since the only function it's going to serve is to forward this domains email.

What's the easiest way to, using an MTA and some modification, get email forwarded from a domain to an email address using SRS? Ideally this would be an MTA that can be installed with yum/rpm and a modification/patching process to enable [SRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Rewriting_Scheme) that can be done without recompiling the MTA.

Finally, it's very possible I'm going about this entirely the wrong way. My only real goal is to forward all emails destined for anything@example.com to a single email address and not have those emails categorized as spam. If this can be accomplished with a service, or some other method than running my own MTA with an SRS patch, that would also solve my problem.

Here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by making a Docker container based off of the [linuxserver.io alpine base image](https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-baseimage-alpine) which runs [postsrsd](https://github.com/roehling/postsrsd), the Postfix Sender
Rewriting Scheme daemon.

postsrsd is installed into the container using the [postsrsd alpine package](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86_64/postsrsd)

- Source code : https://github.com/gene1wood/postsrsd
- Instructions on setting it up : https://github.com/gene1wood/postsrsd/blob/master/README.md
- Example docker compose file : https://github.com/gene1wood/postsrsd/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Deploying it is easy as is configuring Postfix to use it. I've been using this method for a while now and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

1. SRS fore Sendmail (at least I done and used it) is easy doable (I can recall easy ready-to-use solution), describe your problems
2. If domain, which you MX, can be managed by your request: instead of SRS you can just add IP/hostname of yourforwarder to SPF-record of this domain

Comment: 1. Can you provide a link to the SRS fore Sendmail that your referring to? 2. No, what I'm doing is forwarding all email *destined* for all email addresses at a given domain over to a single specific email address. It's not possible to add my MTA's IP to the SPF record of all domains which send me email.